# Trip Aces vs Possible Flush

Tags: all-in, learning, flush

Here's a hand I played today. Worked out for me in the end, but not sure if I played it the best on .5/1 NL

1. I'm dealt A♠6♠
2. UTG opens to 3.5BB, I 3-bet to 6BB, UTG calls
3. Flop comes A♥7♥2♥ hearts
4. UTG checks to me, I bet 5.8BB, UTG calls
5. Turn is A⋄
6. UTG checks to me, I bet 15BB, UTG calls
7. River is K♠
8. UTG checks to me, I shove, UTG folds

I made out with 25 bucks so I can't complain too much, but I am a relatively new player so it would be great to get some feedback!

Comment: In what position were you? Any other info about villain?

Comment: Shoved how much?   This question needs more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Pre not sure what a 3 bet to 6 bb accomplishes.  It has basically no fold equity.  You would need to 3 bet to 10 bb.  A6s is a good but not premium hand that wants to see a flop from middle to late position.  It is not good enough to want to build a pot.

OK with Flop and turn bets.

On the river what hand do you think is going to call a shove. Based on his betting he does not have a set or a flush.  You should be trying to get value from like 7 or 72 with a small bet.

If he set you up slow playing a flush you are toast.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what level of play this is... This can be brilliant or total fish.

If you are playing with normal people, this is pretty bad; if you are playing with God-like pros, this is a decent line (due to the fact that it goes completely against logic and can make people call/fold incorrectly)

1. Min-Reraising with A6s? Why? You are increasing the pot with a drawing hand and most of the open raise range from UTG at least partially dominate your hand. Anything 77+ or Ax has a much higher winrate vs your hand. Small Ace is one of the biggest losers in playable hands; when I play Ax suited, I mostly play for flush (trips with Ace kicker) or winning a small pot.
2. Flop bet was ok, the second barrel on Turn is marginal (your hand only improved against 72, lol) and the all-in on river is suicidal. Flop bet was decent, you can get a smaller pair to call you (pocket pairs, random 2s and 7s). At this point you should be aware that UTG likely has an Ace since he's the raiser.
3. Turn bet was marginal because you might think the second Ace improved your hand, but not as far as the opponent is concerned. If he had you beat on flop with a better Ace, he still has you beat except now it's harder for you to fold. So at turn, what hand do you think would call you that you can possibly beat? A pair of 7? Even 72 is counterfeited and would likely fold. You are LITERALLY only getting called twice incorrectly by K of heart that's not a made flush. No other hand can logically call you and lose to you at that point.
4. River is complete suicide. If he was on a flush draw, he's obviously not calling you now. If he had a 7, do you think he would call you three streets? What on earth are you putting him on? A3 A4 A5? Those are the ONLY three hands out any normal person's range under those conditions. The best way to test yourself is to hear him call you, then see how scared you are internally. If you heard a call, what did you expect him to turn up? You should have seen enough of these kind of bad river shoves to expect any call to crush you at that point.

---

That being said, if you were playing against a pro, he/she might fold a weak flush or a better Ace to you at that point because your betting is so strange. So if you haven't done anything dumb before this hand, it would be a strange place for any good player... Mostly because it's hard to put you on just an Ace at that point. I got to suspect pure bluff or monster hand, I would be folding incorrectly to you maybe 50% of the time (depending on the strength of my hand). However to be fair, on flop/turn, I would have reraised you to identify your hand; if I haven't done that, that river shove would be far too strange for me to call (depending on pot size and shove size of course).